# Prompting the OP to upvote on an idea on Salesforce IdeaExchange

Tags: discussion, comments

Is asking the OP to consider upvoting an idea in Salesforce Idea Exchange (*provided the idea is relevant to the feature the OP is looking for*) an acceptable comment? For example, see comment in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379115/prepopulating-company-name-in-lead-object/379119#379119).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my view: **Yes**.

A link to the Idea Exchange may or may not form a strong answer. It might reinforce and support a statement, for example, that a given feature is not yet supported. But it's definitely acceptable as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal user experience, I've never thought of it as a problem.

I would say, yes, it is acceptable within a comment, or maybe even as an *aside* as part of an actual answer.

My gut reaction is that it would not make an appropriate stand alone answer (but I might could be persuaded otherwise with good arguments).